# Adding SearchView in Simple Layout

Tags: android, searchview

I am trying to add search View inside  Relative Layout, but it's giving a null exception. Any help would be appreciated.I just added SearchView widget in Relative Layout,Basically, I want to add the searchable info which I have created in the searchView and this is my code->

```
SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchbox);
    searchView.setFocusable(true);// searchView is null 
    searchView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

and this is XML Code for the SearchView

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/search_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:tag="sticky"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        >

         <SearchView
             android:id="@+id/searchbox"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            ></SearchView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your error logact ?

Comment: where it is giving nullpointer exception

Comment: @abhishek  which api version you used ?

Comment: not able to find the search view by id , so when i use searchview.setFocusable(true) it gives me an error that -> Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object refernce.

Comment: my API version is 14.

Comment: dud you call `Activity#setContentView` before calling `Activity#findViewById` ?

Comment: yes, I have called that in the first line of my program .

Comment: so try to run `hierarchyviewer` and see what is your views tree like

Comment: @abhishek compare it with my code..

Answer (score 2):

I Used your code and that work fine on my Device let compare with it.

**activity_main.xml**

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/search_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:tag="sticky"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchbox"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            ></SearchView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchbox);
        searchView.setFocusable(true);// searchView is null
        searchView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

It's work compare with it and also `compare the import widget`